# "untervermieten" - trennbar oder nicht

Tags: prefix, separable-verb, conjugation

Das Verb *untervermieten* wird teils trennbar teils nicht trennbar gebraucht.

> Ich vermiete, während ich weg bin, mein Zimmer unter.
>
> Ich untervermiete, während ich weg bin, mein Zimmer.

Beides klingt für mich irgendwie falsch.

- Was ist die richtige Version?
- Welche Version war zuerst da: trennbar oder nicht trennbar?
- Gibt es regionale Präferenzen (Nord vs. Süd oder so)?
- Gibt es weitere Verben, bei denen es unklar ist?

Comment: Ein weiterer Fall ist _überführen_ im Sinn von _eine Leiche transportieren_. Für mich (DE-südwest) ist das nicht trennbar, _untervermieten_ ist trennbar.

Comment: @chirlu "Führen sie die Gleichung über in die Normalform."

Comment: @Em1: Für mich auch nicht trennbar. _Überführen Sie den Ausdruck in konjunktive Normalform._

Comment: @chirlu: schönes Beispiel. Hier klingt für mich beides richtig :)

Comment: @chirlu Zugegeben, ich würde auch immer *Überführen* sagen. *Über-* gehört aber prinzipiell zu den trennbaren Präfixen und ich hab einfach mal geschaut, was denn Google ausspuckt.

Comment: @Emanuel Das hier beschriebene Problem könnte durchaus für viele Language-Learner relevant sein. Es gibt eine Reihe an Präfixen die trennbar sind oder nicht. Im Moment ist deine Frage auf *untervermieten* spezialisiert. Meinst du, es wäre angebracht und möglich, die Frage so zu erweitern, dass *untervermieten* "nur noch" das Beispiel ist und der Titel irgendwas in der Form ist "Wie kann ich herausfinden, ob ein Präfix trennbar ist oder nicht". Möglicherweise wird dann der 4te Punkt deiner Frage überflüssig.

Comment: @Em1: da hast du sicherlich recht, aber das will ich nicht wissen. Mir ging es konkret um untervermieten. Die anderen Sachen wusste ich alle schon. Wenn erweitern, dann auf alle Streitfälle wie "überführen" usw... aber nicht auf trennbar vs. nicht trennbar allgemein denn das ist nicht das Problem hier... wenn jemand anderes meine Frage editiert, dann ist mir das egal, aber selber werde ich mir die Arbeit nicht machen ;)

Comment: @Em1: "*Über-* gehört aber prinzipiell zu den trennbaren Präfixen" - normalerweise nur, wo es auch betont ist. Immerhin ist *über* in *überraschen*, *überrumpeln* und *übernehmen* auch nicht trennbar.

Comment: @Em1: "Führen sie die Gleichung in die Normalform über." würde ich schreiben. Oder "Überführen"

Answer (score 8):

Das Präfix *unter-* gehört zu den Präfixen, die sowohl trennbar als auch nicht trennbar sein können. Dabei kommt es nicht nur auf den Stamm an, mit dem es kombiniert wird, sondern vor allen Dingen auf den Kontext.

Beispielsweise *umfahren* ist mal trennbar (*Fahr das Schild nicht um!*) und mal nicht (*Umfahre das Schild nicht!*).<sup>1</sup>

Bezogen auf das Präfix *unter-* ist es so, dass wenn es eine konkrete Bedeutung hat (und betont ist), ist es trennbar. Ist die Bedeutung eher abstrakt (und unbetont), so ist es nicht zu trennen.

> *unterstellen* mit konkreter Bedeutung:
>   Als es anfing zu regnen, stellten wir uns bei einem Supermarkt unter.
>
> *unterstellen* mit abstrakter Bedeutung:
>   Ich unterstelle dir nicht, dass du es warst.

Den Betonungsunterschied hört man auch, wenn man diese beiden Sätzen mal laut ausspricht:

> Sollen wir uns 'unterstellen?
>   Sollen wir ihm unter'stellen, dass...

Zurück zu deinem Beispiel:
Erstmal gefiel mir auf Anhieb Variante 1 schon besser. Aber vor allen Dingen hat es eine konkrete Bedeutung. Außerdem ist es betont (*Sollen wir das Haus 'untervermieten?*).

Daher plädiere ich für: trennbar

> Ich vermiete, während ich weg bin, mein Zimmer unter.

---

Siehe dazu auch diese [Diplomarbeit](http://is.muni.cz/th/104625/pedf_m/Diplomarbeit.pdf).

---

<sup>1</sup> Hinweis für Language Learner: Die beiden Sätzen ("Fahr das Schild nicht um!" und "Umfahre das Schild nicht.") haben nahezu gegensätzliche Bedeutungen:
Erster bedeutet, man soll nicht gegen das Schild fahren, sondern drumherum, zweiterer hingegen besagt, dass man nicht drumherum fahren soll, sondern dagegen.

Comment: Umgangssprachlich behilft man sich oft mit "tun" + Infinitiv: "Ich tue mein Zimmer untervermieten." Das ist nicht elegant, vielleicht sogar falsch, wird aber oft verwendet.

Comment: @dervonnebenaan, das kommt, glaube ich, nicht im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum vor.

Comment: @dervonnebenaan: Dann versuche "Ich scheue mich nicht, mein Zimmer unterzuvermieten".

Comment: @dervonnebenaan: Klingt für norddeutsche Ohren eher badisch bzw. schwäbisch. Ich würde es aus dem Bauch heraus so formulieren: Ich vermiete mein Zimmer an einen Untermieter.