# "umfahren" – trennbares Verb oder nicht?

Tags: difference, separable-verb

> Wir umfahren die Stadt.
>   Das Auto fährt den Mann um.

Wann ist das Verb *umfahren* trennbar und wann untrennbar?

Comment: abhängig von der Bedeutung: `umfahren` = `to bypass`, `um-fahren` = `to run over`.

Comment: ...und *úmfahren* ist trennbar. *umfáhren*, nicht.

Comment: Related, if not even duplicated (the explanation is the same): http://german.stackexchange.com/q/8437/1224

Comment: How does the question not already contain the answer?

Comment: This double meaning is nicely demonstrated by this gag: https://fb-s-c-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-0/s480x480/15356552_1409369392431328_2915021411414131091_n.jpg?oh=b4c23c39440bc6207135845ae5840f7b&oe=58AF9A53&__gda__=1491858065_805e3f63309688fc68c47346160815a3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das Wort *umfahren* ist der Infinitiv der beiden folgenden Verben:

**umfahren (untrennbar)**

> einen anderen Weg fahren als den, auf dem sich ein Hindernis befindet

**umfahren (trennbar)**

> etwas oder jemanden treffen, während man fährt, sodass dieses etwas oder dieser jemand fällt oder nach unten geht

Je nachdem, welche Bedeutung du meinst, musst du das trennbare oder untrennbare Verb benutzen.

Answer (score 6):

I will just focus on "um" here.

The non-separable version talks about a local "around". There might be something added on top that cannot be guessed or deduced.

> Ich umfahre das Haus - I drive around the house (in sense of avoiding to hit it).
>
> Die Polizei umstellt das Haus - The police surrounds the building.
>
> Ich umgehe die Sperre - I dodge the blockade.

Sometimes it can be a rather abstract use.

> Ich umschreibe das Wort. (I explain it without saying it)

The separable version is all about change of state. Again the precise meaning is hard to guess.

> Ich fahre das Haus um. - I run the house over.

The change in state here is that the house was standing before and is not after. But there are other examples where it is not "over".

> Ich stelle meine Ernährung um.
>
> I change/readjust my diet.
>
> Ich schreibe den Text um.
>
> I rewrite/heavily edit the text.

For a more detailed look check out [this post](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/um-german-prefix-meaning/) on my blog.

Answer (score 3):

Rein akustisch unterscheiden sich diese Verben darin, dass das Präfix der Trennbaren betont wird; wohingegen das Präfix der Untrennbaren stumm bleibt und man den Rest des Verbes betont (wo das Verb ohne Präfigierung normalerweise betont wird). Bleibt das Verb im Satz zusammen, so muss man darauf passen, die richtige Betonung zu machen.

> **Beispiel**
>   Nehmen wir an, Anne fährt mit dem Fahrrad.
>
> 1) *Trennbar.* Anne will dich úmfahren (das wäre ja grausam!)
>
> 2) *Untrennbar.* Anne will dich umfáhren (um dich nicht umzufahren, um dich [und sich] nicht zu verletzen)

Zusätzlich zu anderen Antworten sind die Präfigierungen von Nomen (z.B. `ummanteln=um+Mantel`) und Adjektiven (etwa `umdüstern=um+düster`) untrennbar<sup>(1)</sup>.

Comment: Nope... das untrennbare "um" hat sehr konkret und konsitent den Sinn von lokal "around".

Comment: @Emanuel ach ja, das stimmt.

Comment: Und das ist `über` im untrennbaren `übersetzen` ist auch nicht so metaphorisch, sondern halt einfach etymologisch so gewachsen. http://dwds.de/?qu=%C3%BCbersetzen

Comment: Mein Lieblingsbeispiel: Der Fahrlehrer schimpft: "Sie sollten das Hindernis um*fah*ren, nicht *um*fahren!"