# unter als Vorsilbe/Präfix des Verbes

Tags: verb, separable-verb

Ich habe gemerkt, dass in Verben das Präfix *unter-* manchmal untrennbar ist (z. B. in **unterschreiben**, **unterlassen**) und manchmal trennbar ist (z. B. in **untergehen**, **unterkommen**).

(1) untrennbar
unterschreiben - unterschrieb - unterschrieben
unterlassen - unterließ - unterlassen

(2) trennbar
untergehen - ging unter - untergegangen
unterkommen - kam unter - untergekommen

Tatsächlich gibt es auch Verben die beide Formen haben z.B. **"unterhalten"**.
Hier sind die zwei Formen zwei unterschiedliche Verben und haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen.

Erstens: Stimmt das? Und wenn so, gibt es einige Regeln oder muss man einfach die unterschiedlichen Fälle (Verben) auswendig lernen?

Comment: Es gibt Regeln, lernen muss man leider trotzdem.

Comment: [Wie kann man wissen, ob ein Verb trennbar ist?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/160/1224) ### [“umfahren” – trennbares Verb oder nicht?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/11379/1224) ### [Verbs that are both separable and inseparable](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/15926/1224) ### [“untervermieten” - trennbar oder nicht](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/8437/1224)

Answer (score 1):

Ja, es gibt beide Typen und es gibt auch eine Regel:<sup>[1]</sup> Untrennbar werden die Wortteile durch den Umstand, dass die Kombination eine Bedeutung erhalten hat, die sich nicht (mehr) direkt aus den Komponenten ableiten lässt. Man spricht von **übertragener Bedeutung**. Dasselbe Phänomen gibt es auch für andere Vorsilben, z. B - naheliegend - die Vorsilbe *über-*.

Nicht aufgeteilt wird bei übertragener Bedeutung:

- unterlassen (=nicht tun)
- überlegen (=nachdenken)

Aufgeteilt wird, wenn sich die ursprüngliche Bedeutung der Wortteile erhalten hat:

- untergehen (=herunter gehen) -> geht unter

Und es gibt Fälle, in denen beides möglich ist, dann kann teils aus der Schreibung geschlossen werden, auf welche Bedeutung die Aussage abzielt, teils ist man auf den Kontext angewiesen.

- übergehen (=überwechseln) *Das Erbe geht an mich über.*
- übergehen (=nicht berücksichtigen) *Man darf ihn nicht übergehen.*

Der Lernaufwand für Verben mit übertragener Bedeutung ist sehr hoch: Muttersprachler erwerben sie über Jahre hinweg, sogar mancher Erwachsene hat hierbei Schwächen.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Allerdings hilft diese Regel in den Fällen nicht weiter, wo die ursprüngliche Bedeutung weitgehend erhalten geblieben ist, z. B. beim Wort *überfliegen*.
Auch gibt es Beispiele für Wörter, die in übertragener und hergebrachter Bedeutung ungetrennt bleiben: *übergeben* (=übertragen) *Ich übergebe dir den Schlüssel*, aber *übergeben* (=sich erbrechen) *Ich übergebe mich.*

Comment: Oder auch das oben genannte "unterkommen", das ich nur im Sinne von "etwas schon einmal gesehen/erfahren haben" kenne. Da ist die Verbindung zum ursprünglichen "unter-kommen" nur noch vage zu erahnen, nämlich (so meine ich) dass jemand, der häufig Dinge überprüft wie z.B. Papiere oder handwerkliche Objekte, und entsprechend viele Variationen von einer Sache kennt, so etwas noch nie "unter seinen Händen" hatte.
"Ein Würfel mit 13 Ecken? Sowas ist mir ja noch nie untergekommen."

Comment: @Gloria ich kenne *unterkommen* auch nur in der übertragenen Bedeutung, also ohne Trennmöglichkeit. Das Verb in *Die Idee kam unter die Räder.* hat den Infinitiv *kommen*, das Wort *unter* gehört nicht zum Verb.